# How to get Minimum Spanning Tree Matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, minimum-spanning-tree

Initially, i have 2d array. By using this array i have created a graph with weight on its edges. Now i am trying to use this Graph to make Minimum Spanning Tree matrix but i cant make it as desire. I am using the following code to make graph.

```
 G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(ED_Matrix, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
 layout = nx.spring_layout(G)
 sizes = len(ED_Matrix)
 nx.draw(G, layout, with_labels=True, node_size=sizes)
 labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight")
 output = nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=layout, edge_labels=labels)
 plt.show()
```

And its gives the output like this
[image]

Now i am using MST code, to get the its MST matrix but its gives error like this.

```
 from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
 from scipy.sparse.csgraph import minimum_spanning_tree
 Tcsr = minimum_spanning_tree(G)
 Tcsr.toarray().astype(int)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account example from [docs of scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.minimum_spanning_tree.html), it should be constructed from adjacency matrix of G, not from G.

You might want to replace `G` with `nx.adjacency_matrix(G)` or `csr_matrix(nx.adjacency_matrix(G))` or `ED_Matrix` itself in calculation (assignment) of `Tcsr`:

```
Tcsr = minimum_spanning_tree(nx.adjacency_matrix(G)) #or
Tcsr = minimum_spanning_tree(csr_matrix(nx.adjacency_matrix(G))) #or
Tcsr = minimum_spanning_tree(ED_Matrix)
```

`Tcsr` is a sparse matrix which is later converted to `numpy` array.

Comment: ED_Matrix , is just a 2d array, its not a calculation of Tcsr

Comment: I think I was not clear mentioning calculation. I mean it's an assignment.

Comment: I have replaced the G with nx.adjacency_matrix(G) plus instead of using  Tcsr.toarray().astype(int) i have used  Tcsr.toarray().astype(float). Now its working